# Cannot save any category on Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3, category

When I try to save any categories, I am receiving the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in /var/domains/../vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php:1666
Stack trace:
#0 /var/../vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php(98): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->saveAttribute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), 'url_path')
#1 /var/../vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php(74): Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver->updateUrlKey(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor), 'douche')
#2 /var/../vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88) in /var/../vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 1666
```

Does anyone know what could trigger this error message and how can it be fixed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code was responsible for updating the `url_path` value from here:

```
private function updateUrlKey($category, $urlKey)
{
    if (empty($urlKey)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Invalid URL key'));
    }
    $category->setUrlKey($urlKey)
        ->setUrlPath($this->categoryUrlPathGenerator->getUrlPath($category));
    if (!$category->isObjectNew()) {
        $category->getResource()->saveAttribute($category, 'url_path');
        if ($category->dataHasChangedFor('url_path')) {
            $this->updateUrlPathForChildren($category);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, not sure how, but the `url_path`from the `eav_attribute` table  got removed, so I needed to recreate it !